# How to manage subviews added in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I have a problem in clearing my view, For a particular case I have been adding user names as label into my view, I may have multiple user based on situation, now my problem is, For one case I want to clear the view without popping it, I am not sure how to remove those added labels, I have an idea I can set tag for each label, and I can clear using that later. Any other efficient way is there in this particular case.

Hope my question is clear thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have one more doubts,If I am clearing my whole view then following answers will work fine, If I want to keep some common labels which is not related to user name, then what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews) {
    if(view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]) {
        //do whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all subviews like this:

```
for (UIView *subView in [view subviews])
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
```

Or if you want to access a particular view with tag value of n,

```
UIView *subview = [view viewWithTag:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the following way

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Hope you are asking about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
[labelName removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
for(id viewSub in self.view.subviews)
    {
        [viewSub removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

this will remove all subviews of View

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (UIView *v in [self.relatedView subviews])
{
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call below method and pass the "UIWebView" object as argument:

```
+(void)removeAllSubViews:(id)pObj
{
    NSArray *Array = [pObj subviews];
    for(int index = 0; index < [Array count]; index++)
    {
        [[Array objectAtIndex:index] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

You can also check object like this if you want for any particular object:

```
if(view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]) {
    //do whatever you want to do
}
```

Cheers!